# Java login page lead to next gui

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, authentication

I am creating a java application that requires a login, using Eclipse. I have created 2 GUI's, the first is the login page and the second displays the data.

My problem is, once the user enters the login details, how do I get it to switch to the second GUI?

Comment: please share your code so that other can help where you et stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Have a listener on either a key press or a button click that closes your current GUI and creates the new one.